# Mismatch in Num_Rows and count

Tags: sql, oracle

I am confused over the following mismatch.

```
Select table_name, Num_Rows 
from all_tables 
where OWNER = 'OWNER_NAME' and table_name='TABLE_NAME1';
```

Gave me a result of `401`.

```
select count(*) from TABLE_NAME1
```

gave me a count of `200`. And when tried for `TABLE_NAME2`, both returned same value.
What is happening here?

Comment: Is it possible that you have any oppened session? Maybe in one session you have deleted registries from the TABLE_NAME1 and did not commited.

Comment: The STATS over the table is outdated and yet to be refreshed. You can attempt to analyse the table, using the Dbms_stats package..

Comment: @JorgeCampos : But only one session opened.

Comment: @OracleUser : Will check that also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value in `ALL_TABLES.NUM_ROWS` (or `USER_TABLES.NUM_ROWS`) is just a **statistical** information generated by `analyze table ...` or `dbms_stats.gather_table_stats` procedure. It's not accurate, not real-time information.

Those statistical values are used by **Oracle optimizer** to compute cost of SQL statement and choose execution plan.

Comment: `dba_tables` also have the same things happening right?